# How to get object key and value without knowing directly object key?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm building a React component, that receives an array of objects, but I'm curious about this:

How can I get an object key and value inside map function, without knowing exactly the object key?

**I have this interface:**

```
export interface ISelectOption {
    [key: string]: string;
}
```

**And the type of options variable is an array of ISelectOption.**

**I would like to do something like this, if it's possible:**

```
<select {...rest}>
    {options.map((option, i) => {
       return (
           <option key={i} value={option.key}>
               {option.value}
           </option>
       );
   })}
</select>
```

Comment: Have you tried with `Object.keys()`? https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: @Camilo yes I did, but I would like to learn a new and simpler way, if it's possible.

Answer (score 3):

```
Object.keys(options.object).map((key, i) => (
              <option key={i} value={key}>
               {options.object[key]}
              </option>
            )
```

In this way, without knowing the keys, you can access all of then, looping and access the values.

Answer (score 1):

```js
<select {...rest}>
    {options.map((option, i) => {
       const optionKey = Object.entries(option)[0][0]
       const optionValue = Object.entries(option)[0][1]
       return (
           <option key={i} value={optionKey}>
               {optionValue}
           </option>
       );
   })}
</select>
```

Method `Object.entries()` returns an array of `[key, value]` pairs, so if you are sure your option have only one property then you can use the above snippet, if not then you must iterate over the array returned by `Object.entries()`